# Segue from screen with several buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to write an app using UINavigationViewController.  My first screen has several buttons on it, and on the click of each button, I want to segue to a UIViewController.  I know that I can add a segue on each button, all pointed to the UIViewController that I want to go to, but I was wondering if it is possible to use only one segue that can be fired from each of the buttons.

If that is not possible, I was wondering if it was possible to open the second UIViewController from the first one, on button click, and provide a Back button like the UINavigationView provides.  I did manage to get everything on this idea working, except for the back button.  I mean I can put a standard button somewhere on the screen and go back, but I'd like the standard back button on the UINavigationView.

Phew!  I'm not sure if that makes any sense.

I know that I could also use a tableview, but I'm trying to set this up with buttons.

Thanks

Edit: Thank you to everyone that answered.  I now have this working.  I would vote up the answers, but I don't have enough posts to do it.  I appreciate the answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have separate action functions for each button, suggest that you segue from the main controller to the other controller and create a segue identifier (see xcode procedure below); then, use performSegueWithIdentifier from each of the button action functions. You can also take advantage of the prepareForSegue. To create the segue, control-drag from the left button in the controller in the storyboard to the controller you want to segue to and pick show.

Check the example code in swift that I did for a very similar problem in the SO reference

[Linking View Controllers through button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382575/linking-view-controllers-through-button/30383802#30383802)

You can embed the main controller in a navigation controller and that will give you the ability to navigate back. If you have multiple layers you can also use unwind segue.

Answer (score 0):

Link each button to one single action (ex. buttonClick) in that ViewController and then perform the appropriate segue using pushViewController method on self.navigationController

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {
if(sender.id == self.button1) {
    DestinationViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC_IDENTIFIER"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Or if you already have that 1 segue defined in storyboards you can use

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
```

And use that inside the buttonClick method. Using the 1st example, or the second one as long as the segue you setup in the storyboards is a push then you should already get the back button as that is the default behavior for pushing view controllers onto the navigation stack.